# Validate array items with wheres from items

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

### Context

I have two Order Models which are: `Order` and `OrderItem`.

in OrderController I want to validate array of items. I checked [Laravel array validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#validating-arrays) and found out that I can use something like this:

```
    $customer_id = Auth::guard('api')->user()->id;
    $validate = validator($request->all(), [
        'address_id'    => 'required|numeric|exists:addresses,id,customer_id,' . $customer_id,
        'items.*.product_id'=> 'required|numeric|exists:products,id',
    ]);
```

this is working for "static validation"

---

### Goal

I want to add the following rule

```
'items.*.product_color_id'  => 'required|numeric|unique:order_items,product_color_id,NULL,id,product_size_id,' . $request->product_size_id . ',product_id,' . $request->product_id . '|exists:product_colors,id,product,' . $request->product_id,
```

the problem is how can I make  `$request->product_size_id` changes for each iteration in items??

---

### Note

I thought about making them two controller `OrderController` and `OrderItemController` it will work this way but in this way the client has to send multiple requests (one for creating an Order and one for each item)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/validating-an-array-of-objects?reply=119180). I had to write a for loop for it something like this:

```
$validation = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($request->get('recipients')); $i++) {
    $validation[] = [
            'to.'.$i.'.email' => 'required|email',
            'to.'.$i.'.name' => 'required|string',
    ];
}

$this->validate($request, ['to' => 'required|array'] + $validation);
```

in this way I can get `$request[$i]->get('product_size_id')`